# compare xml files by choosing specific tag name for comparison, list attribute difference of that specific tag

Tags: java, xml, xmlunit-2

Consider:

```
<ParentTag>
    <Firstchild ID="id1" Title="title1">
        <secondchild ID="" Title="">
            <TagOfInterest ID="value1" Title=""/>
            <TagOfInterest ID="value2" Title=""/>
            <TagOfInterest ID="value3" Title=""/>
        </secondchild>
    </Firstchild>
</ParentTag>
```

And:

```
<secondxml>
    <something ID="id1" Title="title1">
        <anotherthing ID="" Title="">
            <TagOfInterest ID="value1" Title=""/>
            <TagOfInterest ID="dinosaur" Title=""/>
            <TagOfInterest ID="nomore" Title=""/>
        </anotherthing>
    </something>
</secondxml>
```

I'm using XML Unit,

Req 1: comparison engine should compare **only** by tag name "tagofInterest".

Req 2: Within that tag if difference exist, compare by attribute.

Implementation which printed only tag names, but didn't give much control over tag of interest or difference by attribute within. Any better suggestion in the way of using XML Unit?

```
        fr1 = new FileReader(expectedXML);
        fr2 = new FileReader(actualXML);
        Diff diff = new Diff(fr1, fr2);
        DetailedDiff detDiff = new DetailedDiff(diff);
        detDiff.overrideMatchTracker(new MatchTrackerImpl());
        detDiff.overrideElementQualifier(new ElementNameQualifier());
        detDiff.getAllDifferences();




class MatchTrackerImpl implements MatchTracker {
  public void matchFound(Difference difference) {
    if (difference != null) {
        NodeDetail controlNode = difference.getControlNodeDetail();
        NodeDetail testNode = difference.getTestNodeDetail();
        System.out.println(printNode(controlNode.getNode()));
        System.out.println(printNode(testNode.getNode()));
    }
}

private static String printNode(Node node) {
    if (node != null && node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        try {
            Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
            t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            t.transform(new DOMSource(node), new StreamResult(sw));
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            System.out.println("nodeToString Transformer Exception");
        }
        return sw.toString();

     }
    return null;
 }
}
```

Comment: What didn't work about your code?

Comment: @Grisha: Above piece of code is extract from, best available solution which i came across [link](https://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2010/01/31/xml-comparison-tutorial-using-xmlunit/) which suppose to print tag which are different on comparison. But the result is recursive (duplicate) and didn't give control over comparison based on specific tag.

Answer (score 0):

From your example I understand that "tagofInterest"s appear as part of a forrest and not as a single element tree inside the document. Otherwise you could use XMLUnit 2.x and only apply the `DifferenceEngine` to the `Element`s of interest.

There is no built-in way in XMLUnit, you will have to provide an implementation of one of XMLUnit's extension points of your own.

The interface you are looking for is `DifferenceListener` in XMLUnit 1.x and `DifferenceEvaluator` in 2.x. Those are responsible for determining whether a difference detected by the engine is supposed to be reported (and if so, how severe it is).

You could provide an implementation of your own that downgrades all differences detected for nodes that are not named "tagofInterest". If you are interested in children of "tagofInterest" as well, it may become a bit more complex as you'd need to travel up to see whether there is a "tagofInterest" parent.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try to implement a custom "Difference Evaluator". I saw documentation of XMLUnit [link](https://github.com/xmlunit/user-guide/wiki/ComparisonFormatter) **getDescription** which had an example, but **getDetails** didn't had an example. I tried searching in WEB, didn't get a sample implementation. Also method parameter explanation link **WhitespaceStrippedSource** is broken.

For now since its urgent requirement, I went the hard way traversing nodes in two xml's and compared them with nodes of interest and made it to work the way required!

Comment: I've just added more  exhaustive javadocs for `WhitespaceStrippedSource` but the parameters are what one would expect from the class-level javadocs. More information about the details of a comparison are at <http://www.xmlunit.org/api/java/2.3.0/org/xmlunit/diff/Comparison.Detail.html>. I think only `value` doesn't explain itself and it depends on the kind of comparison, it may be the name of the element, the number of attributes or a boolean indicating the presence of children, for example.